# Can't get my ntfs partitions UUID in 15.10

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab, automount, ntfs-3g

I installed Ubuntu 15.10, and I can't mount my NTFS partitions I searched a lot and found few solutions and tried them but the funny thing is that everytime I get the UUID's that the partitions had when I had OS X Lion on my PC and now the partitions are different and the UUID's that I write in fstab after entering mount command says there is no such a partitions. I have a Fat32 hdd and it mount with no problem but I can't mount those 2 partitions in the main hdd

It's the return from `fdisk -l` command:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000203804160 bytes, 1953523055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AFE71E0B-0932-46A1-9D20-51590AD74849

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048     409599    407552   199M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2      409640  630292479 629882840 300.4G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdb3   630292480  662292479  32000000  15.3G Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  1050572800 1953521663 902948864 430.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5   782292482 1050571778 268279297 127.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb6   662292480  782290943 119998464  57.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

And it's the return from `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="B87AEC097AEBC26C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9b2f9b2f-01"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="0b11f260-f506-4feb-b27d-8ec98c56f9ee" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2511e248-4a18-4d64-8e5b-667266e50e83"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="3f8ea2fb-5659-4b3a-abee-1fe6c74828fe" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3a8a9067-1bd7-4aa0-8f69-8f93e91f8c9f"
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="a7affebc-b7c8-435a-ac1c-fa9b179e25f9"
/dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="OS X Lion" PARTUUID="242d5ef9-f715-49c3-a6e2-f1e356dce0d3"
/dev/sdb4: PARTLABEL="FILES" PARTUUID="043127c6-625d-4af7-b4be-1259c1beeaf4"
/dev/sdb5: PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="23d03a16-f05f-4e4d-9ae2-d5bc8f8f5e4e"
```

The "Backup" labeled partition is the 2nd har drive and it will mount but I need those "OS X Lion" "Files" and the "dos" partitions that are no longer those name and I dunno why that is like that because I have no longer a HFS+ partitions and sdb2/sdb4/sdb5 partitions all are ntfs but it can't recognize.

For example this is the return from this added line to `fstab` for "OS X Lion" and `mount` command

```
UUID=242d5ef9-f715-49c3-a6e2-f1e356dce0d3  /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

return:

```
mount: can't find UUID=242d5ef9-f715-49c3-a6e2-f1e356dce0d3
```

I appreciate any help from you guys.

p.s: I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and I am just a User.

Comment: `/dev/sdb2` is Mac, not NTFS.  It won't work right that way there.  It looks like `/dev/sdb4` and `/dev/sdb5` are your NTFS partitions.  Try using their UUIDs.

Comment: Problem is here that I have no HFS+ partition for 2 years :-/

Comment: `fdisk` usually isn't lying - so there is a difference between your claims and physical evidence.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have an `UUID` for your partitions on `sdb`, and that you use `PARTUUID` instead (which won't work).

You may either:

- add an UUID and use it: `gparted(8)` can normally do it, or `ntfslabel(8)` with the `--new-serial` option
- use `PARTUUID=` in `fstab`